# Import php array into javascript dataset

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have extracted some data and organized them in an array in .php file.

Now I want to visualize that data using d3 methods in another file with .html extension. I would like to import that array into the dataset.

I'll try to post the code or what makes sense here:

```
<?php

        // data extraction from a bunch of xml files.
        // stored all of that in an array ---- $topics 
        // sorted the array by frequency of the elements 

        $topic_count = array_count_values($topics);

        echo '<p>' . "Array Testing " . '</p>';

        foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
                echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 
        }

    ?>
```

The output from the foreach is:

```
tim harper published - 5
TIM HARPER Published - 3
Updated - 1
Illustration Garnotte - 1
cour rejette - 1
cour supr me rejette les peines obligatoires du gouvernement harper - 1
Chris Wattie - 1
Stephen Harper - 1
contenu publication - 1
information - 1
juif canadien - 1
```

When I do `echo json_encode($newArray,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`
the output is:

```
{
    "tim harper published": 5,
    "TIM HARPER Published": 3,
    "Updated": 1,
    "Illustration Garnotte": 1,
    "cour rejette": 1,
    "cour supr me rejette les peines minimales obligatoires du gouvernement harper": 1,
    "Chris Wattie": 1,
    "Stephen Harper": 1,
    "contenu publication": 1,
    "information": 1,
    "juif canadien": 1
}
```

I have tried doing:

```
script type = "javascript">
            var dataset = <?php echo json_encode($newArray,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
        </script>
```

but I can't get the data to use.

Seems like I'm getting out of topic here, but my question is how can I import that data in my html file. (same folder ofcourse)

Comment: I assume `son_encode` is a typo? What exactly is the problem? Why doesn't your code work?

Comment: `var dataset = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode( $newArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ); ?>)`

Comment: yes that was a typo. Fixed it... I don't know what it's not working.

Comment: I tried saving the whole file as an html file but it just prints the code. SO I decided to do the javascript on a different html file, but I need the data to work with from this code above.

Comment: that didn't work as well @Dendromaniac

Comment: @mudoskudo Would you mind telling me the response in console of the code I suggested?

Comment: Hang on @mudoskudo, Try this: `var dataset = JSON.parse( '' + <?php echo json_encode( $newArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT ); ?> + '' )`

Comment: @Dendromaniac it actually shows the data in the console inspector, but not on the actual browser page. Interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the data in a text file and parse it.

```
var jsonphp = '<?php echo $d = file_get_contents("json.txt"); ?>';
var jsondata = $.parseJSON(jsonphp);
```